# How can I allow users to edit text that will be displayed on a custom post type archive page?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, archives, page-template

I like the custom post types Wordpress offers. Most of the time I like the way that the archive of custom posts is displayed. For example if you have a custom post type of `top_hats` you can visit `yoursite.com/top_hats/` if it is set as publicly queryable.

I realize that a description can be set for custom post types, but I am looking for something that supports the built in rich text editor.

I also realize that you can edit a post-type archive template, something like `archive-top_hats.php`, which could be edited to have a custom message in the top of it - however I am looking for something that will give the user more control.

The expected (and ideal) behavior would be if you had the Admin Bar enabled and you were logged into the Wordpress site. Imagine if you visited the `yoursite.com/top_hats/` page and there was the menu bar option that said "edit this page" which made editing that page as simple as editing any other page. If you added a message and then updated the page and viewed it, you would see your content at the top, followed by the `custom_post_type` entries below (in archive format).

Seems like that's how it should work, but I really am not sure the ideal way to get that integrated.

Answer (score 1):

What your asking for is basically what is called a sticky post for archives (or a taxonomy), a widget or a content block.

Either way you will have to write some code. To tie it into the admin bar is pretty easy, for example  using `admin_bar_menu`, it has several hooks.

Personally I would just create another CPT called "sticky archive posts" (or something) and use that with the `WP Query` to create a sticky archive post and link it in the admin bar.

Comment: The admin bar is not really the important takeaway from my paragraph, was just trying to show where i wanted to edit / add the content in.